# Does everyone always eat, drink and sleep for free everywhere in Middle-earth?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-hobbit, middle-earth, economics

Maybe it has to do with the specific and unique circumstances in which the characters we follow in *The Hobbit* and *The Lord of the Rings* find themselves, but it seems to me that everyone always assumes that food is free of charge and that people generously offer them both food, drinks and lodging with no payment whatsoever expected or implied.

It seems like it's "all or nothing"; either they won't even acknowledge your existence/peril at all, or they let you in and give you more than you can handle to eat and drink, and let you stay as long as you feel like it. Oftentimes offering stories and valuable information as well.

Merry and Pippin, for example, "look around" in the camp areas for where "people are eating" when they get hungry. The thought never seems to enter their minds that they would have to pay some sort of money or beg to be allowed to eat. They seem to just organize mass-meals where anyone nearby can just silently slide in and help themselves to all kinds of food and eat with people who barely will notice them.

There never seems to be any scarcity of food, except when they are completely alone in the wilderness. And even then they stumble upon some soldiers who bring them to their hidden cave and fill up their Hobbit-tummies with yummy edibles and allow them to rest in peace, even appointing servants to bring them fresh water and whatnot.

I used to be frustrated by how little money/valuables they bring when they initially set out on their journey, but it seems like they never actually need to buy food or anything. Stuff is just given to them, and even though they seem grateful and polite, it's still somehow "expected". Even at the *Prancing Pony*, which is literally a commercial establishment, I can't recall that they ever mention money.

Is this just how the fictional world of Middle-earth works? Or do they just get lucky? Was it actually like this back in the day in real life?

Comment: "Was it actually like this back in the day in real life?" no.

Comment: "*'Leaving the letter aside, I promised Gandalf no less. Barley, he says to me, this friend of mine from the Shire, he may be coming out this way before long, him and another. He'll be calling himself Underhill. Mind that! But you need ask no questions. And if I'm not with him, he may be in trouble, and he may need help. **Do whatever you can for him, and I'll be grateful, he says.** And here you are, and trouble is not far off, seemingly.'*"

Comment: *We cannot count on getting anything to eat between here and Rivendell, except what we take with us; and we ought to take plenty to spare;*

Comment: Granted the price isn't mentioned but buying food and renting rooms is just assumed to have a cost. It's just not vital that the *minutae* be covered in the narrative.

Comment: *"He [Frodo] ]suspected now that he had fallen in with a rascal, and he thought uncomfortably that he had brought only a little money with him. All of it would hardly satisfy a rogue, and he could not spare any of it."*

Comment: By "the camp areas", do you mean an encamped army? Because I would imagine that "I am part of the same army as you, please share your rations with me" would be a reasonable request, and wouldn't involve transfer of money.

Comment: Everywhere after Bree, they are either entirely on their own in the wilderness, or the guests of someone who has a lot of food and who really, *really* wants their endeavor to succeed.

Comment: If everything in Middle-earth was free, then what was the point of the Dwarves hoarding all that gold under the mountain in the first place?

Comment: Treasure hoarding is a rather different thing than having a debit card.  I doubt Smaug was using a single nugget of its hoard to buy drinks at a tavern.  We do know that the Lake Men traded barrels of apples to the elves in Mirkwood.  Presumably they got something back in return.  Meat? Cash? Beer?

Comment: @Paulie_D ailed it: Tolkien did not care about economic transactions. Notice that he did not care about eliminating bodily waste, washing & drying socks and other garments while camped near water, and he says absolutely zilch about Krebbs cycle.

Comment: @Ethan I didn't mention Smaug, but the Dwarves. Presumably they hoarded the gold as it was valuable, meaning they could buy stuff with it (of course some of the later Dwarf kings went a bit nuts, but that's another story). Also, using money and bartering could in principle coexist (at least for while). Finally, I really doubt Gondor didn't collect taxes in coins ;-)

Comment: Guest-right was a thing, people certainly did get free food in the ancient world, plus e.g. Galadriel and Faramir outfit them because they want them to succeed. The Fellowship does largely depend on this, but in the case of Pippin and Merry, it's all what you'd expect: Merry is eating in a military camp, and Pippin is *explicitly*, textually, receiving military rations - which he finds insufficient. (They also loot Saruman's stash.)

Comment: @Hans_Olo:   I'm not at all sure the dwarves horded gold because it was valuable.  Gandalf says in FotR while describing mithril that "The wealth of Moria was not in gold or jewels, the toys of the Dwarves; nor in iron, their servant..."  I take that to imply that they kept the gold around because it was pretty, not because it was valuable.

Comment: @Ethan It's also implied that the rings of power influenced that hoarding behaviour.

Comment: @OrganicMarble That's not _quite_ true. Or rather, yes, staying in an inn would cost you money both for lodging and food, but that was relatively rare in the first place. For the most part, people relied on lodging in some stranger's house (or barn), and it was a big deal hosting strangers. Not to mention that it was the primary way that people got to know what's going on in the world at large - they got both entertaining stories and sometimes valuable information out of their kindness :)

Comment: @Ethan He is comparing the value of mithril to the value of everything else, combined.  Mithril was of such extreme value, that including their gold, jewels, and iron when enumerating their wealth is just superfluous.  The division of the horde in The Hobbit (and the almost-war between dwarves, men, and elves) makes it quite obvious that gold and jewels are valuable.

Comment: It's also worth noting that, except for Sam, all the hobbits we follow are wealthy (quasi-)nobility. They have enough money that neither spending it nor giving others things for free are normally a big deal for them, so there isn't any plot interest to be gained from the story paying attention to the act of paying.

Comment: Honestly, it sounds like you're describing basic **hospitality**.  Modulated somewhat by the difficulty of travel in the time, thus today you'd offer dinner or coffee and they'd drive home, back then if they were at your home in the afternoon they were there for the night. And yes, hospitality is a largely digital thing - you either ignore someone, maybe give them some alms, or you invite them into your home and put on the band.  The treatment you give them is less about who they are, and more about who **you** are.

Answer (score 112):

Firstly, as Lord of the Rings is conceived to be taking place long ago in essentially our world, yes, to some degree, people were expected to provide free food and lodging for strangers. This was known by various names, such as the [Xenia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenia_(Greek)) in Greece, but it was widespread in the ancient world and well into the Middle Ages, if not later.

But outside of Rivendell and Lothlorien, this is mostly not even what's happening! And in both instances, Elrond and Galadriel have other reasons for feeding and providing for the Fellowship - they want them to succeed and are themselves involved in its mission!

There are only a few instances where the Hobbits need anything from anyone, as they don't encounter many other people:

0. With **Farmer Maggot** (zero because I almost forgot him), Maggot is a close friend of Merry and of Pippin, through Merry. He encounters them on the Road, sees they are in some trouble, and out of friendship feeds them and helps them. I don't think anyone, even today, would question this.

   > ‘Well, it's time you made it up. Especially if you are coming back to live in Buckland. Old Maggot is really a stout fellow - if you leave his mushrooms alone. Let's get into the lane, and then we shan't be trespassing. If we meet him, I'll do the talking. He is a friend of Merry's, and I used to come here with him a good deal at one time.' (The Lord of the Rings)
1. In **the House of Tom Bombadil**, we have an normal example of the relationship between guests and hosts - and besides, Tom has just rescued the Hobbits from mortal peril and doesn't seem to have a high regard for their ability to survive on their own in the Old Forest. Since he's taking them home, of course he's going to feed them! If anything, it would be quite strange to charge people you've invited to stay the night after rescuing, even for us.

   > Thank you!’ said the hobbits, one after the other. Tom Bombadil burst out laughing. ‘Well, my little fellows!’ said he, stooping so that he peered into their faces. ‘You shall come home with me! The table is all laden with yellow cream, honeycomb, and white bread and butter. Goldberry is waiting. Time enough for questions around the supper table.
2. In **Bree**, the Hobbits paid their way, or at least they were expected to, until Butterbur realized they were the ones Gandalf had told them to look out for.

   > ‘How should I know? He's welcome to go where he will, **so long as he pays in the morning.** There's Mr Took, now. he's not vanished.’

   I would suppose Butterbur did not likely make them pay, as he was told to help them as a favor to Gandalf, whom he feared and respected as a friend, and out of embarrassment over the incident with the wraiths, but they normally would have been expected to.

   > ‘Ah! That was Gandalf, if you know who I mean. A wizard they say he is, but he's a good friend of mine, whether or no. But now I don't know what he'll have to say to me, if I see him again: turn all my ale sour or me into a block of wood, I shouldn't wonder. He's a bit hasty. Still what's done can't be undone.’ [...] I'll do what I can to set matters right, and if there's any help I can give, you've only to name it. [...] Mr Butter-bur paid for [a replacement pony] himself, and offered Merry another eighteen pence as some compensation for the lost animals. He was an honest man, and well-off as things were reckoned in Bree; but thirty silver pennies was a sore blow to him, and being cheated by Bill Ferny made it harder to bear.
3. In **Rivendell**, the Fellowship is, of course, the guest of Elrond and the Elves, who are supporting them and outfitting them for the destruction of the Ring.
4. In **Lothlorien**, the Fellowship was expected after communication with Rivendell, and they are of course eager to do whatever they can to help the Fellowship accomplish their mission.
5. **Among the Orcs**, Merry and Pippin were mostly robbed of all they had, and given food to keep them alive. I suppose this counts as a transaction.
6. **Among the Ents**, Treebeard takes Merry and Pippin into his home; again, it would seem quite strange for him to then charge him for Ent-draught.
7. In **Isengard**, the Hobbits loot Saruman's foodstuffs.
8. In **Rohan**, when not direct guests of the King, Merry seems to be eating as part of the military encampment. Although some armies did historically require soldiers to buy their own food, this does not seem to be the case in Rohan.
9. In **Gondor**, Pippin is taken into the service of Denethor, and fed rations, which he complains are insufficient.
10. With **Faramir**, he is at one point feeding captives, and at another outfitting Hobbits he desperately hopes succeed.

Comment: Great answer!  And it's worth remembering that in those days of no fast communication, the arrival of a non-dangerous stranger was a *major* break in an otherwise-boring life and meant news and conversation. Food and lodging was cheap payment for all but the poorest.

Comment: I visited a village on the Island of [Rennell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rennell_Island#Lake_Tegano) once, and we were welcomed, fed, and given a place to sleep, and were expected to exchange news. There was no cash payment. A couple of the younger chaps from the village accompanied us next day. There was no suggestion that we would pay them; they were friendly, and happy to go somewhere else for a couple of days.

Comment: One could add The Green Dragon Inn in Bywater, which presumably charges for its popular food and drink.

Comment: Will add that Tolkien's academic areas certainly include a lot of cultures with myths that push expectations of hospitality to travellers - Norse, Celtic etc mythologies all contain powerful figures, sometimes gods, rewarding or punishing those who obey or break the requirements to give hospitality free of charge to travellers.

Comment: Great answer! It did make me wonder, how would Merry and Pippin even pay Treebeard? Other than literally starting a war for them, I mean.

Comment: " I don't think anyone, even today, would question this." Just leaving this here... https://www.newsweek.com/zara-larsson-debate-sweden-house-tradition-not-feeding-guests-1711336

Comment: @Darren Swedes and Norwegians just don't want to inflict the bad local cuisine on their guests... Seriously: I can confirm that the default in the North is that everybody always pays for themselves. Giving out drinks is particularly uncommon. But this is more based on the fact that people don't see the point of gifts that the receiver could just as well afford themselves, and prefer not to enter into relationships with implicit strings attached. However _helping out in need_ is a completely different story; in Norway this falls under [dugnad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dugnad).

Comment: @Blueriver Yeah, I'm not even sure Ents would have any concept of "money".  What does seem unusual is that they would have a concept of "food".  Being trees, they get their nutrients from the soil and photosynthesis presumably.  How would they know what those little flesh-beasts need to survive?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman They don’t do they? The only sustenance Treebeard gives the hobbits is Ent-draughts.

Comment: @Darren Or drinks, I guess.  What even is an "Ent-draught" exactly?  Trees probably wouldn't drink anything besides water.  Hobbits cannot live on water and sunshine alone (heck they can't even manage to live on 3 meals a day like most people).  So presumably there's something else in there...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman given how important animals (bees, squirrels etc.) are for plant life I imagine that they have some inkling at least.

Comment: It could also be that they paid, for example, in Bree, but since it is a normal expectation, not needed to be mentioned in the story.  We don't hear much about them need to relieve themselves in the books either, but I assume they did so.  Just not an interesting or needed thing for the story telling.

Comment: @chadbag: They were definitely expected to pay at least until Barliman finds out who they really are, he says as much in the book.

Comment: @Shamshiel Yes.  And they may have.  Not a necessary story element to show the actual payment.  -- "Frodo dropped 5 copper pieces into the hands of the good innkeeper as they went out to pack up for their imminent departure."   Just isn't needed for the story.  The lack of verbiage mentioning payment doesn't mean that payment is not being made.

Comment: @chadbag: I agree they might have, I just think it’s unlikely THEY had to because of Gandalf’s instructions and the animals being stolen; Barliman surely paid MUCH more for the new pony and in compensation than what he charged for a night’s stay.